# Responsive table in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My question is quite simple, how do I make this table responsive using twitter bootstrap 4? Below  is a [JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/5ntwzpxg/9/).

```html
<div class="some-table-section">
<div class="container">
    <table class="table some-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col">Plan 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Plan 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Option 1</th>
                <td>$1</td>
                <td>$2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Option 2</th>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Option 3</th>
                <td>Unlimited</td>
                <td>Unlimited</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"></th>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Select this plan</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Select this plan</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

What I would like to have is a responsive version of this table such that `plan 2` is below `plan 1` in the responsive version. PS. You can find the current CSS in the [JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/5ntwzpxg/9/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check Bootstrap Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/#responsive-tables

Simply wrap your table with `.table-responsive`

Basic example:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
       ...
    </table>
</div>
```

You can have breakpoint specific responsive table using class `table-responsive{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did check that and I did try adding the `table-reponsive` class. However, that did not work for me. Even whe I do that, I still have the horizontal scroll.

Comment: You wrote you want `plan 2` below `plan 1`. This is a bad idea and I don't think you can make it easily. Tables do not work the same way as `div` columns - you can't break a row.

Comment: Check out "CSS pricing tables". I suppose this is what you need. You can create much better layouts using CSS, not html table.

Comment: Can you link that?

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=css+pricing+tables&client=opera&hs=Cze&sxsrf=ACYBGNTrpSAB7Z1DKamsOe_nyz_UXwB-Mw:1572633282154&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu3ZPB08nlAhWyTt8KHe2FBtwQ_AUIESgB&cshid=1572633395043011&biw=1600&bih=790